# Random number in c# which should be exactly random every time?

Tags: c#, random

i am trying to generate random number for my mental math quiz game. But i think i am doing something wrong.Please help me to correct my code.Please try to include some sort of explanation, why my code is incorrect. Thanks in advance!

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;


    namespace MindTraining
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the digits of first number ");
                int a=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the digits of second number");
                int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Random RandomClass = new Random(DateTime.UtcNow.Second);

                int RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next(10^(a-1), 10^a);
                Console.WriteLine(RandomNumber);
    }


    }
```

}

What i am trying to achieve is , I want user to enter number of digits in number a and number of digits in number b

Then program would generate random number, say user entered 2 for a ,then program have to generate numbers between 0 to 10(Random Number, Every time different)

if user entered 3 for a, then between 10 to 100,

Similar thing for b, and then calculating product.Number should not repeat more than 2 times, during program run time.

Ok, i changed my  code to

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace MindTraining
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the digits of first number ");
            int a=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the digits of second number");
            int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Random RandomClass = new Random(DateTime.UtcNow.Second);
            double num1=Math.Pow(10,a-1);
            double num2=Math.Pow(a,1);
            int num3 = Convert.ToInt32( num1);
            int num4=Convert.ToInt32(num2);

            int RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next(num3,num4);
            Console.WriteLine(RandomNumber);
}}
```

// But still not getting result, I throws error,

This one worked!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace MindTraining
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the digits of first number ");
            int a=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the digits of second number");
            int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Random RandomClass = new Random();
            double num1=Math.Pow(10,(a-1));
            double num2=Math.Pow(10,(a));
            int num3 = Convert.ToInt32( num1);
            int num4=Convert.ToInt32(num2);

            int RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next(num3,num4);
            Console.WriteLine(RandomNumber);
}


}






        }
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing wrong if we don't know what you're expecting this code to do exactly.

Comment: If you want something "exactly random" (I'm assuming you mean something like "likely to be different each time"), then why are you limiting yourself to only 60 possible seed values?

Comment: "Number should not repeat more than 2 times, during program run time" is incompatible with "exactly random".  A truly random sequence can always have arbitrarily long repetitions of the same value.  That's not the cause of your problem, but it's worth understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is there any reason you want to use a seed value that is so limited? Why not use

```
Random RandomClass = new Random();
```

which takes a default time based seed value for your object?

Also, use Math.pow(base,exp) to calculate the range for your Random.next() calls as:

```
int RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next((int)Math.Pow(10,(a-1)), (int)Math.Pow(10,a));
```

In your code, the error occurs because,

```
double num2=Math.Pow(a,1);
```

returns a itself. So, your maxvalue in the Random.next() is lower than your minvalue, which is logically incorrect. This is the error, I got from running your code, that is apart from the fact that you are missing a closing brace at the end.

Also, you must realise that there is no such thing as a perfectly random number generator. All these are pseudo-random generators. They follow the normal distribution of numbers on the number line. So, to say that a number will not be generated more than twice in one execution is not feasible unless you store all the numbers generated and keep checking against them. This should be a last resort, only is case of dire requirements.

Comment: Hi Darnir, i tried this. It says RandomClass.Next take int argument and math.pow give double argument, so this will not work.Also i edited my code, following your recommendation. Please give follow up.

Comment: Oh okay.. right, my bad, should have explicitly type casted it.

Answer (score 1):

The `^` operator in C# means "exclusive or" (XOR), not exponentiation. Read about it here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/xor .  Try [`Math.Pow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx) instead.

Comment: I'm unsure whether this is a case of "great minds think alike" or "fools seldom differ"... only time will tell!

Comment: Thanks, more help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

^ is not a raise to the power operator in c#.
Use [Math.Pow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx) for this.

Answer (score 0):

While generating a *TRULY* random number you cannot suppose that the number is different all the time,hope you got the point. So you need to additionally make sure that the number is different each time.